# Punctuating one sentence that has multiple speakers

Tags: punctuation

I not sure how to punctuate this sentence. I want to string together a group of critical comments into one sentence. The idea is that there is more than one speaker, so can I keep it within one set of quotation marks, and where would the question marks go. It is how I want the sentence to read, so there is a flow rather than a staccato effect.

‘Why because a thief had tried to steal a handbag, which never should have been left unattended in the first place; you have to concentrate on the game — and was he really up to the captaincy?’

Comment: Multiple speakers = multiple sets of quotation marks.

Comment: We can tell you about standard rules, but many authors do violate standard grammar and punctuation rules to achieve an effect. We can't really help you decide when to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do put everything in one set of quotation marks, no one can tell you not to!  But it's not standard English, it's some kind of experimental project ;)  It would usually be punctuated something like this:

```
"Why?"
"Because a thief had tried to steal a handbag--"
"--Which should never have been left unattended in the first place--"
"You have to concentrate on the game!"
"...and was he really up to the captaincy?"
```